# Discord RPC отображается только у меня, а у других нет

Tags: python, discord

Решил добавить в своей проект поддержку Discord RPC. Вроде написал код, запускаю, RPC есть. Попросил друга посмотреть, есть ли активность у меня в профиле, нет. Так же я проверил с других аккаунтов, есть ли у меня активность, нет. Как пофиксить?

Код, который должен был показывать активность у всех:

```
import pypresence

client_id = "1101876327927259207"
RPC = Presence(client_id, pid=os.getpid())
RPC.connect()

quotes =[
"V3 вышла!",
"Рекод!"
]

RPC.update(large_image="icon", details="The best assistant ever!", state=random.choice(quotes), buttons=[{"label": "Обновления тут ", "url": "asdasdasd"}])
time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотри:

1. Зачем тебе задержка, если нет цикла?
2. У тебя не импортирована библиотека time
   а так, у меня такая же проблема, щас пытаюсь найти решение.
   ***Отредактировал***
   Кнопки не позволяют показывать активность у остальных...

Вот код который отображает у всех:

```
from pypresence import Presence
import time, random

client_id = "*******************"
RPC = Presence(client_id)
RPC.connect()
quote =["V3 вышла!","Рекод!"]

while True:
    RPC.update(
    details="Первый",
    state=random.choice(quote),
    large_image="yandex-music",
    )
    time.sleep(15)
```